# Continuous Integration to Test Flight using Al tool on Jenkins for Multiple Apps

Tags: xcode, jenkins, testflight

I am trying to setup Continuous Integration for IOS App using altool to upload IPA file to Test Flight. We have Two apps in one user Account. Now I want to upload two Different IPA's into their builds. But I couldn't found any command to do that.

Command: 
 $/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Support/altool

```
 $ altool --upload-app -f /path/to/app.ipa -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD
```

how do I upload two different App's(IPA) in one user account using altool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload app's using altool.

Write below script/commnd in **Execute Shell** of **Add Build Step** drop down.

- In the first step you need to go to the path where ALTOOL is. (Note :- Make sure your Xcode version is greater than or equal to 8.3)
- In second step perform commnd for upload app to testflight.

  ```
  cd  /Applications/Xcode8.3.3/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Versions/A/Support/

  ./altool --upload-app -f PathOfYourIPA -u yourAccountID -p yourAccountPassword
  ```

For ex. My Path for IPA is :-

**/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/JOB_NAME/build/artifacts/IPAName.ipa**

Comment: I have two apps in my account.  if i use above command to upload ipa. where it goes?

Comment: From above commnd, only one app that is defined in your path, is goes to the testflight.

Comment: Yes, Exactly. where it goes if I have two apps setuped in that same account. for Example I have App A and App B in one account. If I use App A ipa and above command. where it will goes to App A or App B?.

Comment: If you have two apps in same account it means both apps have unique bundle id. When you open your account and goto my apps, you saw two apps seprate named App-1 and App-2. Right ???? Then if you use above commnd with App-1 ipa then it will goes to App-1..

Comment: Perfect. I am looking for this answer.